# how can i bring the months in calender order like from jan to dec in scala dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe

```
+---------+------------------+
|    Month|sum(buss_days)|
+---------+------------------+
|    April|             83.93|
|   August|            94.895|
| December|             53.47|
| February|             22.90|
|  January|             97.45|
|     July|            95.681|
|     June|            23.371|
|    March|            35.957|
|      May|              4.24|
| November|              1.56|
|  October|              1.00|
|September|             93.51|
+---------+------------------+
```

and i want output like this

+---------+------------------+
|    Month|sum(avg_buss_days)|
+---------+------------------+
|  January|             97.45
  February|             22.90
     March|            35.957
     April|             83.93|
|      May|              4.24
      June|            23.371
      July|            95.681
    August|            94.895|
| September|           93.51
   October|             1.00
  November|             1.56
  December|             53.47|
+---------+------------------+

this is what it is i did
df.groupBy("Month[order(match(month$month, month.abb)), ]")
And i got this.....
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "Month[order(match(month$month, month.abb)), ]".Here Month is Column name in dataframe

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you supply the structure of the dataframe (is month currently String?) and also what did you try so far

Comment: Hi Arnon, thanks for reply

Comment: here it is what i did so far, can you look at he question i just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the Month Into Date form and sort the items should do.

Please find the snippet `unix_timestamp(col("Month"),"MMMMM")`

```
Df.sort(unix_timestamp(col("Month"),"MMMMM")).show
+---------+-------------+
|    Month|avg_buss_days|
+---------+-------------+
|  January|        97.45|
| February|        22.90|
|    March|       35.957|
|    April|        83.93|
|      May|         4.24|
|     June|       23.371|
|     July|       95.681|
|   August|       94.895|
|September|        93.51|
|  October|         1.00|
| November|         1.56|
| December|        53.47|
+---------+-------------+
```